# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/restassured/path/json/mapper/factory/JsonbObjectMapperFactory

Tags: java, jar, testng, rest-assured, web-api-testing

while making a GET api request using restassured jar, my program is throwing following error while running as TestNg

**OutPut:**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/restassured/path/json/mapper/factory/JsonbObjectMapperFactory
    at io.restassured.config.RestAssuredConfig.<init>(RestAssuredConfig.java:41)
    at io.restassured.RestAssured.<clinit>(RestAssured.java:421)
    at SimpleGetTest.GetWeatherDetails(SimpleGetTest.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.restassured.path.json.mapper.factory.JsonbObjectMapperFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 28 more
```

my java program is as bellow

**SimpleGetTest.java**

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.Method;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;

public class SimpleGetTest {

    @Test
    public void GetWeatherDetails()
    {   
        // Specify the base URL to the RESTful web service
        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://restapi.demoqa.com/utilities/weather/city/";

        // Get the RequestSpecification of the request that you want to sent
        // to the server. The server is specified by the BaseURI that we have
        // specified in the above step.
        RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given();

        // Make a request to the server by specifying the method Type and the method URL.
        // This will return the Response from the server. Store the response in a variable.
        Response response = httpRequest.request(Method.GET, "/Hyderabad");

        // Now let us print the body of the message to see what response
        // we have received from the server
        String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();
        System.out.println("Response Body is =>  " + responseBody);

    }

}
```

**external jar used:**

1. rest-assured-4.2.0
2. json-path-4.0.0
3. xml-path-4.0.0
4. groovy-2.4.7
5. commons-lang3-3.0
6. httpmime-4.3.1

Comment: Looks like you use incompatible versions of your jar files

Comment: how to resolve this, can you comment which jar shall i use

Comment: Mavenize your project, and also I wouldn't advice you to use different versions of artifacts which have the same groupID, if you are using 4.2.0 of Rest Assured then use 4.2.0 of JSON-Path and XML-Path

Comment: @ArpitAggarwal I am not sure but the new classes are introduced in 4.0 off rest-assured: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/ReleaseNotes40, so maybe you have also an old version of these jar in your classpath. See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/4.2.0 for compatibility of jars

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using `rest-assured` of version 4.2.0 then you should keep all the related JARs like `json-path` and `xml-path` of same version and

As a best practice al was use the latest jars which has include most of the bug fixes
Looks like you need to use latest version of json-path for now you can use

```
io.rest-assured:json-path:4.3.0
io.rest-assured:xml-path:4.3.0
```

Also make sure your runtime environment classpath includes those JARs and with the same version used while compile time.

Edit :

Also include

```
io.rest-assured:rest-assured-common:4.3.0
```

The below is the list of JAR's that are required for you

[image]

For PKIX error

If -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore is present in your JVM arguments, Java will use the keystore specified with that argument. You can verify whether the -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore parameter is causing problems by running the SSLPoke test and specifying the same JVM argument to use that keystore.

For example:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/my/custom/truststore SSLPoke jira.example.com 443
```

You are trygin to access a secure URL . hence you need to import the public certificate in your keystore first.

Comment: after applying io.rest-assured:json-path:4.2.0,io.rest-assured:xml-path:4.2.0 i am getting error as java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/restassured/common/mapper/factory/ObjectMapperFactory

Comment: @ArpitAggarwal - Include `io.rest-assured:rest-assured-common:4.3.0` as well

Comment: same issue continues in spite of adding io.rest-assured:rest-assured-common:4.3.0

Comment: Are your running them using IDE or standalone jar ? @ArpitAggarwal

Comment: i am running the program in Eclipse IDE

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to mavenize your project ?

Comment: try updating all your jars `json-path, xml-path, rest-assured, rest-assured-common` to `4.3.0`

Comment: After appying all above jar i am getting this

Comment: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)

Comment: works like charm after update with same version rest-assured, json-path, xml-path